# My OpenGL bitmap program is crashing?

Tags: c++, opengl, bitmap

I am using OpenGL and the bitmap library at http://partow.net/programming/bitmap/ to make a program load a bitmap on my screen. I have made it to load a bitmap on my screen, but when I try to use p.x and p.y (From GetCursorPos) to load an image at the position of the cursor, the application crashes.
Here is my code:

```
void Image(HDC hDC, string File_Name, int x_position, int y_position, int length, int height)      // Image()
{
File_Name = "C:/Users/David/Pictures/" + File_Name + ".bmp";      // add a full path to the file name
bitmap_image image(File_Name);                                    // Open the bitmap
unsigned char red;
unsigned char green;
unsigned char blue;
restart:
image.get_pixel(x_position, y_position, red, green, blue);        // Get the red green and blue from x_position and y_position     and store it in red green and blue. 
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);                                           // Make a pixel at x_position and y_position with red green and blue.
glColor3ub (red, green, blue);
glVertex2f (-1 + 0.0015 * x_position, 1 - 0.003 * y_position);
glVertex2f (-1 + 0.0015 * x_position, 0.997 - 0.003 * y_position);
glVertex2f (-0.9985 + 0.0015 * x_position, 1 - 0.003 * y_position);
glEnd();
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3ub (red, green, blue);
glVertex2f (-1 + 0.0015 * x_position, 0.997 - 0.003 * y_position);
glVertex2f (-0.9985 + 0.0015 * x_position, 1 - 0.003 * y_position);
glVertex2f (-0.9985 + 0.0015 * x_position, 0.997 - 0.003 * y_position);
glEnd();
if (x_position==length)               // If x_position equals to length of bmp set x_position to 0 and add 1 to y_position.
{
if (y_position==height)               // If bmp is done loading go to done.
{
goto done;
}
x_position = 0;
y_position = y_position + 1;
}
x_position = x_position + 1;
goto restart;
done:         
SwapBuffers(hDC);                    // Put it on the screen         
}



int main()               // int main()
{
POINT p;
if(GetCursorPos(&p))
{
Image(hDC, "Image", p.x, p.y, 1340, 678);
}
}
```

I am using Dev C++ on Windows 7.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you already set up an OpenGL context outside this function? https://open.gl/context

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set up an OpenGL context in order for this to work. Look at this: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)

Comment: I have already done this, I just have it in another file. But thanks for the help!